# KerasTensor' object is not callable

Tags: conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

this code related to baengali VQA system.this code work on question model.i got an error
here is my error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-c644a382e307> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 ques_input = Input(shape=(max_length,), name = "ques_input")
      3 e1 =Embedding(vocab_size, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix_train], input_length=max_length,trainable=False)(ques_input)
----> 4 l1= LSTM(64,kernel_initializer=initializers.he_normal(seed=42),kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001),return_sequences=True)(e1)
      5 l2= LSTM(64,kernel_initializer=initializers.he_normal(seed=42),kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001),return_sequences=True)(l1)
      6 #l1= LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.3)(l1)

TypeError: 'KerasTensor' object is not callable
```

i tried simple LSTM that couldn't prove expected result